# Realistic uses for pointer to pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I've seen example codes in books that demonstrate pointers such as `int*** ptr`, `int ****ptr`, etc. What are some real life examples that this would be used ?

Comment: You would use that type of argument when you really want your coworkers to loathe you.

Comment: Code obfuscation? :-)

Comment: A multi-dimension array.

Comment: A string array as output parameter.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? I'd say there's never a good reason for more than one level of indirection in C++; wrap a pointer in a friendly class if you want to do anything complicated with it (and prefer references where possible).

Comment: Without pointers to pointers to pointers, we wouldn't have [three-star programmers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are mostly used for dynamically allocated multi-dimensional arrays.

Example:

```
int width = 100, height = 2, depth = 50;
int*** array3d;
array3d = new int**[width];
for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    array3d[x] = new int*[height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        array3d[x][y] = new int[depth];
    }
}

// Now array3d can be used like this:
array3d[42][0][1] = 666;
```

Comment: So why do we use multi-dimensional arrays? Such as, what are some examples where multi-dimensional arrays are used?

Comment: For example games where the level is a 2D plane of tiles and you want easy access to the tiles by their indices, e.g. `map[x][y]`.

Comment: quite a few applications actually. For example in the 3D world you could use them for Voxel data, or fluid simulations etc.

Comment: Since C normally uses the last dimension for "width" (such as the number of columns in matrix), perhaps the example should swap the usage of depth and width, so that the last dimension is pointer to an array of integers (columns), the middle dimension is a pointer to array of pointers to arrays (rows), ...

Comment: @rcgldr But isn't it more logical to access the dimensions in this order: x, y, z, instead of z, y, x?

Comment: @zenith - width, height, depth is the way that Fortran handles multi-dimensional arrays, but depth, height, width, is how C handles multi-dimensional arrays, similar to the way an odometer or numbers work, the right most digit is the least significant digit.

Comment: @rcgldr What do you mean with "the way *x* handles multi-dimensional arrays"? Isn't it up to the programmer to handle and decide how their arrays are handled?

Comment: @zenith - Take the case of a true multidimensional array in C, such as | int  a[3][4][5]; | , and then create a pointer to the first element of a: | int *pa = &a[0][0][0]; |, then pa[0] == a[0][0][0], pa[1] == a[0][0][1], pa[4] == a[0][0][4], pa[5] == a[0][1][0], pa[20] == a[1][0][0] . It would seem more "compatible" to keep this same ordering for dynamic arrays (ones accessed via pointers to pointers to ... .

Comment: @rcgldr But that wouldn't work with dynamically allocated multi-dimensional array since the elements are not laid out contiguously in memory, if I'm right?

Comment: @zenith - the elements of the last dimension would be contiguous, the same as the last dimension of non dynamic multidimensional array. Another variation on this would be a pointer to an array of some fixed size, such as | int (*pa5)[5] | which would be a pointer to an array of 5 integers, or a pointer tot the first row of a [...][5] integer matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Such pointers are extremely rarely used, and I would be willing to bet that in the vast majority of the cases where they are used, they could have been avoided by restructuring the code to make it more simple.  (And also more understandable and more maintainable.)

However, pointers (*p) and pointers to pointers (**p) are very common, which means that the language has to offer the ability to declare at least those, so there is absolutely no reason to put an arbitrary limit at two levels of indirection and forbid anyone from declaring any more levels of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

The most i've ever used is `char***`.

I was parsing a file and had to split it in words per lines.

So you had :

```
char*** parsed_file;
char** first_line = parsed_file[0];
char* first_word_of_first_line = first_line[0];
```

Comment: `error_code get_parsed_files( char***** result )` and `error_code get_parsed_directories( char****** result )`.

Comment: @Yakk Can't wait to see the `get_parsed_hard_drive` and `get_parsed_virtual_machines` !

Answer (score 1):

Another place where you will run into multiple levels of indirection is when you need a function to write to a pointer parameter.  Assume the following code:

```
void bar( T *arg )
{
  *arg = new_value(); // write new value to what arg points to
}

void foo( void )
{
  T x;
  bar (&x);  // write new value to x
}
```

Substitute `T` with a pointer type `Q *`:

```
void bar( Q **arg )
{
  *arg = new_value(); // write new value to what arg points to
}

void foo( void )
{
  Q *x;
  bar (&x);  // write new value to x
}
```

Substitute `Q` with another pointer type `R *`:

```
void bar( R ***arg )
{
  *arg = new_value(); // write new value to what arg points to
}

void foo( void )
{
  R **x;
  bar (&x);  // write new value to x
}
```

etc., etc., etc.

The semantics are the same in all three cases; we're writing a new value to `x`.  The only thing that changes is the type of `x`, and the number of levels of indirection.